# Use-cases for alternate entry point in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

What is an alternate entry point in a BlackBerry application?
When should we use this?
Is it for doing background processing?

If the alternate entry point has an icon, then which icon is shown in the BlackBerry app folders -- the main application icon or the alternate app icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed for launching apps that run in the background. See [Running in the Background](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2010/06/running-in-the-background-part-2/) and [Creating an Always-On Experience](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/23567/Always_on_1380986_11.jsp#Creating_an_always-on_experience_with_Bookshelf_1380989_11) for more details.

Comment: More generally, alternate entry points can also have a presence on the ribbon with a separate icon and separate arguments passed into the entry point method. However, it's less common to have a compelling reason to want two user-visible entry points, and more common to have one dedicated for some non-user-initiated use (like startup initialization, background service running independently from user-interaction, and so forth).

Comment: So both the background app and UI app running concurrently.. rite? 

Thanks @Eric and @Viktor

Comment: Yes. The background app gets launched automatically and stays running unless it exits explicitly. Very useful feature for responding to system events, waking up automatically, etc.

Comment: then whats the use of icon for the background process app..
well that the application running and creating desktop alerts and the UI application may to monitor the alerts with details.. rite?

Comment: Alternate entry points aren't just for background apps, although that's perhaps the most common case.